# Android Studio 1.1.0 Log.d cannot output, but Log.e is OK

Tags: android, logging

I have traced into source code, and I found Log.d into Log.java->public static int w(String tag, Throwable tr), why?
but when I use Log.w, all things ok.
is any configuration I configured error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Huawei Ascend P6, I have searched one solution to solve the problem about debug level log not outputting, following is that:
1, open dialing panel and input ：*#*#2846579#*#*   , click into testing menu selecting interface;
2, open menu : ProjectMenu – background setting – LOG settings
3.LOG Enabled;

Comment: Interesting, so it was your device itself (and not your IDE) which was filtering log messages by log level, and you were able to change this by dialing a special code to bring up a hidden menu.

Comment: Yes, it's that, if you have huawei mobile phone ascend p6 or p7, you can try it.